# Does empty text occupy space in database

Tags: mysql, database, int

Does empty `text(type)` occupy space in database ? One column of database table is merely used, if data is inserted in this column, the size will be no more than 2 digit integer. First-fall, I set `int(2)` for this column, but it kept `0` value even if it is empty. No matter how much, but space is occupied even there is 0 value. Am I right ? So I switch `int` to `text` thinking that `text` field would be empty if no data is inserted. Is my assumption right ? Does empty text occupy space ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-strings

Comment: WIth InnoDB, storage is allocated in pages. If our change allows more rows to fit into each page, then the amount of storage for the table could decrease. But if we are still fitting the same number of rows on a page, then there won't be any impact on the space used by the table.

Answer (score 4):

Blank space will take minimal space :
i) one bit in the NULL bitmap
ii) two bytes for length (which will be zero when NULL.

Answer (score 3):

Does empty text(type) occupy space in database ?

```
 Yes, it does. But it doesn't contribute to table row size. Text and Blob stored in different area of memory. It contributes only 9-12 bytes.
```

Though, Different storage engines handle the allocation and storage of this data in different ways in MySQL, according to the method they use for handling the corresponding types.

Int(2) will always occupy 2bytes to hard drive, irrespective of what you store either(0) or max(2^8) and it will contribute 2bytes to table row size.

Answer (score 1):

I think empty text = NULL, so yes, it should occupy space. Wait for others. That is what I am thinking about it.

Answer (score 1):

yes, Empty means it we are passing a null value. so it take spaces.

Comment: In MySQL, stored int a TEXT datatype, an empty (zero length) string is different than a NULL value.  A NULL value would require zero bytes of storage, a zero-length string would require two bytes of storage, for the length field.  (The bits for indicating NULL values are reserved in the row header. The number of nullable columns determines the amount of storage reserved for the null indicators, this space is fixed, and doesn't depend on the data stored in the row.)